# Ninject: System.Security.VerificationException : Operation could destabilize the runtime

Tags: .net, nunit, ninject, code-coverage, sharpdevelop

I have the following code which works well, when tests are executed.

But then i try to run these tests + code coverage calculation (SharpDevelop 4)
it throws the exception.

Can somebody describe why this happens?

> SetUp : System.Security.VerificationException : Operation could
>   destabilize the runtime.

```
  [TestFixture]
  public class NinjectExamplesTest
  {
    private interface IExampleInterface
    {

    }

    private class ExampleInterfaceImplementation : IExampleInterface
    {

    }

    private class ExampleClass
    {
      [Inject]
      public IExampleInterface ExampleProperty { get; set; }
    }      

    IKernel kernel;   

    [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
      kernel = new StandardKernel();
      kernel.Bind<IExampleInterface>().To<ExampleInterfaceImplementation>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestStandardResolving()
    { 
      // setup

      // business
      var result = kernel.Get<IExampleInterface>();

      // verify
      result.Should().NotBeNull();
      result.Should().BeOfType<ExampleInterfaceImplementation>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestPropertyResolving()
    {
      // setup
      var exampleClass = new ExampleClass();

      // business
      kernel.Inject(exampleClass);

      // verify
      exampleClass.ExampleProperty.Should().NotBeNull();
      exampleClass.ExampleProperty.Should().BeOfType<ExampleInterfaceImplementation>();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you really trying to test Ninject?!

Comment: I'm just trying to start using it instead of Unity :)
And unfortunately started to receive this exception.

Comment: You really should be unit testing your own code, not third party tools. Why not test technology you use(asp.net, winforms, webforms, entity framework, etc) or whole .NET Framework then? And if you look at [Ninject on github](https://github.com/ninject/ninject), you can see that source already includes tests.

Comment: @archil it is very common to discover third party interfaces using integration tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) uses [PartCover](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4) to do the code coverage. This looks like it may be related to a [known issue](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4/issues/52) (see the end) when running with assemblies that use the [AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.allowpartiallytrustedcallersattribute.aspx) or similar.

The fix should be included in the latest maintenance release but I don't know whether SharpDevelop have packaged the latest release.

Comment: no worries - the other answers (critiquing your testing approach) should have been comments. I actually use Unity with Moq to create an auto mocking container for my tests - so I and [many others](http://elegantcode.com/2010/01/03/unitymoq-automocker-or-automockingcontainer/) also do the same. We all have our preferences when it comes to testing...

Comment: I'll also try to add [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) to SharpDevelop this year as it has branch coverage support and is the one being actively developed.